# Configuring prometheus mesos-exporter running on mesosphere DCOS

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, prometheus

I am trying to set up mesos exporter on my mesosphere DCOS cluster. The link I am referring to is https://github.com/prometheus/mesos_exporter. The JSON file I have used is :

```
    {
      "id": "/mesosexporter",
      "instances": 6,
      "cpus": 0.1,
      "mem": 25,
      "constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]],
      "acceptedResourceRoles": ["slave_public","*"],
      "container": {
            "type": "DOCKER",
            "docker": {
              "image": "prom/mesos-exporter",
              "network": "BRIDGE",
              "portMappings": [
                  {
                      "containerPort": 9105,
                      "hostPort": 9105,
                      "protocol": "tcp"
                  }
              ]
            }
          },
      "healthChecks": [{
          "protocol": "TCP",
          "gracePeriodSeconds": 600,
          "intervalSeconds": 30,
          "portIndex": 0,
          "timeoutSeconds": 10,
          "maxConsecutiveFailures": 2
      }]
    }
```

But only meter exposed to Prometheus is 'mesos_exporter_slave_scrape_errors_total'. What are the other meters which mesos exporter exposes to Promethues. The readme from the github of mesos-exporter says that we need to provide command line flags, but if I want to run mesos exporter as a docker container how should I specify the configuration?

EDIT - The meter 'mesos_exporter_slave_scrape_errors_total' gives non-zero value, indicating that errors occurred during the scrape.

EDIT - After adding the 'parameter' primitive my JSON file looks like:

```
{
  "id": "/mesosexporter",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 25,
  "constraints": [["hostname", "UNIQUE"]],
  "acceptedResourceRoles": ["slave_public"],
  "container": {
        "type": "DOCKER",
        "docker": {
                   "image": "prom/mesos-exporter",
                   "network": "BRIDGE",
                   "portMappings": [
                                     {
                                       "containerPort": 9105,
                                       "hostPort": 9105,
                                       "protocol": "tcp"
                                     }
                                   ],
                   "privileged": true,
                   "parameters": [
                                     { "key": "-exporter.discovery", "value": "true" },
                                     { "key": "-exporter.discovery.master-url",
                                       "value": "http://mymasterDNS.amazonaws.com:5050" }
                                 ]
                 }
  },
  "healthChecks": [{
      "protocol": "TCP",
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 600,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "portIndex": 0,
      "timeoutSeconds": 10,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 2
  }]
}
```

Mesos version: 0.22.1

Marathon version: 0.8.2-SNAPSHOT

The app remains in 'deploying' state after using this JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the args primitive solved the problem. The equivalent docker command is **docker run -p 9105:9105 prom/mesos-exporter -exporter.discovery=true -exporter.discovery.master-url="mymasternodeDNS:5050" -log.level=debug** 
As the parameters 'exporter.discovery', 'exporter.discovery.master-url' and 'log.level' are for the image entry point and not for 'docker run', 'args' has to be used.

The format for 'args' as added in the working JSON is:

```
   "args": [
      "-exporter.discovery=true",
      "-exporter.discovery.master-url=http://mymasternodeDNS:5050",
      "-log.level=debug"]
```

Comment: Glad to see it worked out in the end. Was it your intention to be able to start the Prometheus mesos-executor container each time it failed? I have been using it with `--restart=always` option of `docker run` command.

Answer (score 2):

> But only meter exposed to Prometheus is 'mesos_exporter_slave_scrape_errors_total'. What are the other meters which mesos exporter exposes to Promethues.

If the mesos-exporter is listening on port 9100, you can check **`http://<hostname>:9100/metrics`** to know what metrics are being exposed. I am referring the `prom/node-exporter` that I have setup on one of the systems.

> but if I want to run mesos exporter as a docker container how should I specify the configuration?

I am assuming you're POST'ing this JSON file to the Marathon REST API to start Docker containers. If that is indeed the case, you can specify additional options using `parameters` JSON directive. More info can be found on [Marathon docs](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html) under the section **Privileged Mode and Arbitrary Docker Options**.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Right, you need to pass the correct options to the mesos exporter.If you plan to run just one exporter, you probably need to set parameters to `[ "-exporter.discovery", "-exporter.discovery.master-url", "hostname-of-master" ]`

Comment: @fish are "-exporter.discovery", "-exporter.discovery.master-url", "hostname-of-master" accepted as parameters for docker run command ? as I am running mesos-exporter using the docker image prom/mesos-exporter.

Comment: Actually I just checked the docs and the right marathon json parameter to use would be 'args'. Something like this should do it: https://gist.github.com/discordianfish/2b53f3b08a9b33cbfc2f

Comment: When I run the docker command **'docker run -p 9105:9105 prom/mesos-exporter -exporter.discovery=true -exporter.discovery.master-url="mymasternodeDNS:5050" -log.level=debug'** I get all meters at the 9105 port.  @Dharmit I tried both parameters and args both don't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Dharmit thanks for sharing the link of the doc page. I think the 'paramater' primitive should be working for me ideally. But when I add it to my JSON file, my app is stuck in 'deploying'. Could you please review my JSON file as given in below answer.

Comment: @fish thanks for sharing your idea for the JSON file. I tried with the 'args' primitive in JSON file, but that did not export any additional metrics to Prometheus or on 9105 port. Could you review once my JSON file as given in below answer.